# AES decryption fails in forge but works in crypto-js

Tags: javascript, cryptography

I am decrypting a message string at a regular interval. After studying multiple jsperf's I've noticed forge and stanford are faster than cryptojs - I need that extra speed as I am bound to support older mobile devices, so I'm attempting to migrate.

Here is the working crpto-js code:

```
var feed = message.data.msg;
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(_iv);
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(_key);

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(feed.substr(32), key, { iv: iv });
feed = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

And now the non-working forge code:

```
var feed = message.data.msg;
var iv = forge.util.hexToBytes(_iv);
var key = forge.util.hexToBytes(_key);

var buffer = forge.util.createBuffer( feed.substr(32) );
var cipher = forge.aes.createDecryptionCipher(key);

cipher.start( iv );
cipher.update( buffer );
cipher.finish();

feed = cipher.output.toHex();
```

After decryption with forge I get a random jumble of characters. While stepping through the code, the only thing of note is a failure in forge/aes.js, line 969:

```
if(count > (Nb << 2)) {
    rval = false;
}
```

Is firing and returning false.

I'm at a loss here as both libraries use CBC as the default for AES so everything should just work.

Comment: You are converting your message from hex in your "forge" implementation, while you do not do such a thing in the cryto-js code, could that be an issue? (update your code otherwise!)

Comment: @owlstead: I've tried it both ways and it fails, thanks though I stripped that bit out!

Comment: Why are you truncating the message at 32 characters? Have you tried not doing that? You may have a padding issue here.

Comment: As per the provider, the encoded bit starts at the 32 character mark... I'd roll with what you are saying except it works perfectly in cryto-js...

Comment: Was the encryption performed with crypto-js or something else? If so, it may just be working only because crypto-js is doing something somewhat proprietary. Truncating your encrypted data and then trying to decrypt it is usually not a good idea -- it requires that you understand how the underlying cipher and padding scheme work.

Comment: Encryption is performed in a .NET library server side. Essentially, the encrypted string is produced and appended to a 32 character string then pushed to the client.

Comment: Note that ciphers (and most cryptographic functions) work on bytes, not on characters or strings. Handling any message - especially ciphertext - as string may give unexpected results. Ciphertext may contain non-printable character codes, including control characters, the null character and even values that do not have a character representation.

Comment: I'm sure it must be changed to hex before sending it off the client or else crypto-js wouldn't work, right? Meaning, if the message were malformed from the server because of missing characters, crypto-js wouldn't be able to decrypt either...

Comment: Oh, if the incoming string is utf-8, see my answer as a possible fix.

Comment: I was just looking at the cryptoJS source ... it looks like if you pass a string to its decrypt() methods then it uses an OpenSSLFormatter to parse the input. There must be a special encoding applied to the encryption string.

Comment: @ChaseB.Gale No, not hex. Binary, or to be more precise, byte arrays. Cryptography works on bytes, hexadecimal encoding is just a convenient method of representing bytes in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing:

```
var buffer = forge.util.createBuffer( feed.substr(32) );
```

To:

```
var buffer = forge.util.createBuffer( forge.util.decode64( feed.substr(32) ) );
```

And changing:

```
feed = cipher.output.toHex();
```

To:

```
feed = cipher.output.getBytes();
```

Comment: It looks like it may be base64-encoded. One sec, let me edit my answer.

Comment: Ok I tried that and now the decoded string is looking almost identical to each of it's precessors (still garbled though, just an unexpected result)

Comment: Ok I can't post data as the server devs aren't rotating keys yet.

Comment: The string being asserted here: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/branches/4.x/test/tests/format-openssl-test.js?r=650 looks very similar to the raw string I see coming across the wire, I think you are right about the ssl.

Comment: ...although the server dev on chat is insisting it's a regular string, encrypted, then pushed over the wire.

Comment: Ok, well "regular string" has a lot of different meanings. The encoding for the encrypted data must be known in order to figure out what calls need to be made to decode it before passing it to forge. Can you ask the server dev if it's just base64-encoded encrypted data? Is password-based encryption used at all here?

Comment: When you say you're getting garbled output, are you still translating to hex? You should remove that cipher.output.toHex() call and change it to cipher.output.getBytes() if your original input was just text.

Comment: If I encrypt something with forge and base64-encode it, then run the CryptoJS code you have above, it works just fine. I suspect adding that forge.util.decode64 code above and then changing cipher.output.toHex() to cipher.output.getBytes() may solve your problem.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I just noticed your domain is hosting this project, is this your baby? If so, awesome work!

Comment: Great! I'm glad that fixed it. Yes, it's a Digital Bazaar project... thanks!